# Echo data from a SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am not that new to PHP and SQL Statements, but I have stumbled upon this problem, and am at a loss on how to fix it. My query isn't displaying the commentID like I want it to.

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT `commentID`, `blogID` FROM blog_comments WHERE blogID = ':postid' ORDER BY commentID DESC LIMIT 1";
  $query_params = array(':postid' => $row['postID']);
try {
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  die($e->getMessage()); // Don't echo $e on prod. site
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
  <?php echo $row['commentID']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
comments
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes in your `WHERE blogID = ':postid'`

that is treated as a [string literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

```
WHERE blogID = :postid
```

Doing error checking would have spotted that.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html